# How to setup detailed metrics for apigateway using CDK and C#

Tags: aws-api-gateway, aws-cdk

I want to enable this functionality in the API Gateway so I can see 500 errors at a method level and not at the entire API Gateway level.

[image]

However there doesn't seem to be any way in CDK code to set that from what I tried. This is what I am trying

```
        Resource v1Resource = apiGateway.RestApi.Root.AddResource("v1");
        Resource myResource = v1Resource.AddResource("my_res", new string[] { "OPTIONS", 
        "POST" },
        APIResourceExtensions.AuthApiKeyHeaders, APIResourceExtensions.AllOrigins);
  

        LambdaFunction myFunc = new(this, $"{id}-my-function", new LambdaFunctionProps
        {
    
        });

       myResource.AddMethod("POST", myFunc.Function, null, null,
           authorizer: authorizer, authScopes: new string[] { "my/func", "myFunc/read" 
        }, authType: AuthorizationType.COGNITO, apiKeyRequired: false);
```

What do I need to add to enable that checkbox?